# Submersion and orientability

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^4\to \mathbb{R} $ be a smooth map. If $f $ has a regular point at $p\in\mathbb {R} $, then is the submanifold $f^{-1}(p) $ always orientable? I guess one of the Mobius band, $RP^2$ and the Klein bottle may be a counterexample. Is it the right way?

Comment: $f$ has a regular _value_ at $p$.  A regular _point_ is a point $x\in\mathbb R^4$ where $df_x$ is surjective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is orientable, because you can choose the normal vector field: $$f^{-1}(\{p\}) \ni x \mapsto \left({\rm grad}\,f\right)(x) \in T_x(f^{-1}(\{p\}))^\perp,$$ for every $x$. Bear in mind that this map is defined globally on all of $f^{-1}(\{p\})$. So the Möbius band, for example, is not $f^{-1}(\{p\})$ for any smooth map $f$ and any $p \in \Bbb R$ (maybe at most locally).